# How to catch event in masstransit application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I have the project with microservice architecture,
I have an api gateway project where i have the controller to call the respective actions.

In the registration microservice i am doing the database insert and upon successful save
i am publishing an event.

This event i am trying to catch on the api gateway project in the consumer.I am having issues here while catching the event

```
private readonly IRequestClient<RegistrationNotifyEventMessage> _registrationNotifyPublisher;

public record BaseRegistrationEventMessage
{
    public long RegistrationId { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
}
public record RegistrationNotifyEventMessage : BaseRegistrationEventMessage
{

}
 public record RegistrationPublisherResponse
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

And on the consumer on the registration microservicea fter the successful db save operation i am publishing an event.

```
await _registrationNotifyPublisher.GetResponse<RegistrationPublisherResponse>(new RegistrationNotifyEventMessage
                        {
                            RegistrationNumber = "1234",
                            RegistrationId = request.RegistrationId
                        });
```

And the below my code in apigateway to capture the event .

```
public class RegistrationNotifyEventPublisher : IConsumer<RegistrationNotifyEventMessage>
{
    private readonly ILogger<RegistrationNotifyEventPublisher> _logger;
    public RegistrationNotifyEventPublisher(ILogger<RegistrationNotifyEventPublisher> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<RegistrationNotifyEventMessage> context)
    {
        await context.Publish<RegistrationNotifyEventMessage>(new
        {
            DossierNumber = context.Message.DossierNumber,
            RegistrationId = context.Message.RegistrationId,
            PublishedTime = DateTime.UtcNow
        }, context.CancellationToken);

        await context.RespondAsync(new RegistrationPublisherResponse
        {
            IsSuccess = true
        });
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Here i am getting error retry failed after 4 tries. retry settings can be adjusted in clientoptions retry. I am using masstransit and asp.net core

How should I fix this code to get the event in the api gateway consumer?